# System.typeloadexception при Marshal char[] (string) х86, х64

Tags: строки, x86, x86-64, marshal

Использую `Visual Studio 2017`. Пишу на `C#`. Платформа х64. При маршалинге структуры, которая содержит `char[]` (или `string`) генерируется исключение `System.typeloadexception`. Если сменить платформу на х86, то проблема уйдет. 
Я понимаю, что это как-то связано с тем, что размер указателя на участок в памяти меняется с 4 байт на 8 байт. Кто-нибудь может поподробнее объяснить, почему генерируется исключение? И как это связано с х86 и х64?

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public struct DEVMODE
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public Int32 field1;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 10)]
        [FieldOffset(4)]
        public char[]/*string*/ field2;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DEVMODE mode = new DEVMODE();
    }
```

Если изменить FieldOffset(4) на FieldOffset(8) то проблема уйдет.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public struct DEVMODE
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public Int32 field1;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 10)]
        [FieldOffset(8)]
        public char[]/*string*/ field2;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DEVMODE mode = new DEVMODE();
    }
```

Массивы на х86 нужно выравнивать по 4 байта, а на x64 по 8 байт?